# Unstable speed of gameloop

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, timing

I'm making a simple breakout game in OpenGL(-es) on Android. Initially I had the updating of the game's state and the drawing calls in the same loop: onDrawFrame. Now I decided to split up the two, only leaving the rendering calls in onDrawFrame, and the gamestate was managed in another Thread:

```
public void run() {
    Log.d("GameLogicThread", "GameLogicThread started");
    final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000000000 / 30;
    long endingTime;
    int timeElapsed;
    long startingTime = System.nanoTime();

    while (!running) {// wait for it...

    }
    while (running) {
        endingTime = System.nanoTime();
        timeElapsed = (int) (endingTime - startingTime);
        Log.d("timeElapsed",Integer.toString(timeElapsed));
        if (timeElapsed < UPDATE_INTERVAL-timeElapsed){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeElapsed);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        startingTime = System.nanoTime();
        Game.updateGame(timeElapsed);
    }
```

EDIT
I now have changed the code like this ^^, but it still doesn't work correctly..

Is it something in the loop itself that's wrong, or should I look outside (Probably not, since it worked great before moving the code). What should I do?

Comment: "since it worked great before moving the code" <-- so what changed?

Comment: First I had the code to update the game's state (Like object positions), like the one above, in my drawing loop called onDrawFrame (look it up, it gets called automatically by openGL), and now I have it in a seperate Thread, from wich you can see the run() method above...

Comment: @pst I think by "worked great" he means that the timeElapsed was always > 0 which is not better. Now he made it run much faster.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The loop doesn't look broken to me.</strike> The move to separate threads is definitely a good one or you would have serious problems when the rendering of a frame takes too long.

Have you tried to use [nanoTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) for more accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few logical errors which are pointed out/discussed in the comments below:

```
    endingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timeElapsed = (int) (endingTime - startingTime);
    // Why is the "elapsed" time being waited? Hmm.
    // If *any* wait is being done (I'd recommend sleep(0) for starters)
    // it should be the MAXIMUM desired cycle time MINUS the
    // currently used cycle time (MINUS some fudge factor).
    if (timeElapsed < UPDATE_INTERVAL) // I dislike hanging blocks...
        try {
            Thread.sleep(timeElapsed);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // The game needs to know the TOTAL time elapsed since
    // the last update, not the time "until before the yield".
    // This will likely be passed fictitiously small values as
    // it is only time the the LAST updateGame took to run.
    Game.updateGame(timeElapsed);
```

I would never expect to see timeElapsed (passed to updateGame) below say 10ms with `sleep(...)` and the corrected time calculations.

However, it may not have the required precision (increasing the minimum cycle length to say 1/30 sec, which would result from the fixed math, would make this *less* important): see Cristian Vrabie's answer for a suggestion on a higher-resolution timer. (There may be some better 3rd-party alternatives designed just for this -- there is in "normal" Java -- I don't program Android ;-)

Happy coding.

Comment: Correct! I missed the fact that he passed the time before yield. Talking of yield, it might be better than sleep(0), and there's no exception to catch: http://goo.gl/B4AzF Not sure if Java doesn't do this already under the covers of a 0 sleep, tho.

Comment: I've now (slightly) altered my code above, but it still isn't resolved. Also, do you have some good example of such 3rd-party alternative?

Comment: @user717572 The update code is still incorrect. Please refer to *all* the comments above. What does each comment mean/imply? How can the *(multiple)* issues be addressed? And *what in heck* is `timeElapsed < UPDATE_INTERVAL-timeElapsed` supposed to do?